# How I access process.env variables in react html file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have HTML file as follows below and process.env variables as 
`process.env.var1='abc'` but once application is loaded the variable is undefined.

```
res.send(`
   <html>
   <head>
       <link href="${process.env.var1}" rel="stylesheet">

       </script>

   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="react-root"></div>
  </body>
</html>`);
```

Comment: Can you show how you pass your environment variables into your Node instance?

Answer (score 2):

process.env is a global variable provided by your environment through Node Js. But we don't have Node js in the browser, we are going to use webpack.

So you can use configure webpack DefinePlugin to create global constants

```
// webpack.config.js
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
 plugins: [
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': '"production"'
        }
    })
 ]
};

//index.js
console.log(process.env);

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

Comment: Introducing a bundle loader to pass a variable from the server to the client? Bit overkill wouldn't you say?